# Is There A Way to Aggregate PDF Letters the Way Labels are Aggregated

Tags: search

When you create labels you can aggregate them by address.  I want to be able to do this for PDF letters as well so that they match the labels.  I have looked all over and do not see another way to do this.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

We came to the conclusion that this is not possible and that is because of the tokens that would be needed for the letters once they were aggregated.